# C#/WPF: How do I separate structure from styles like in web programming?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

When programming for the web, you normally separate structure from style using a separation of HTML and CSS.

How do I accomplish the same in a WPF project? All the examples I find use "inline" styling. Is it possible at all? Does it even make any sense in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull out all styles into separate XAML files and only reference them from the XAML files that define your UI structure. `ResourceDictionary`s are your friend here.

Actually that's both common *and* recommended in WPF.